# A single-line loop with a mandatory pair of braces in Java

Tags: java, loops

The code in the following snippet works just fine. It counts the number of objects created using a static field of type `int` which is `cnt`.

```
public class Main
{
    private static int cnt;

    public Main()
    {
        ++cnt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int a=0;a<10;a++)
        {
            Main main=new Main();
        }

        /*for (int a=0;a<10;a++)
            Main main=new Main();*/

        System.out.println("Number of objects created : "+cnt+"\n\n");
    }
}
```

It displays the following output.

```
Number of objects created : 10
```

The only question is that when I remove the pair of curly braces from the above `for` loop (see the commented `for` loop), a compile-time error is issued indicating

> not a statement.

Why in this particular situation, a pair of braces is **mandatory** even though the loop contains only **a single statement**?

Comment: `Main main=new Main();` is a declaration, not a statement.

Comment: @Mysticial: a declaration with initialization.Why isn't the initialization part considered a statement ?

Comment: @Razvan I see no technical reason why it can't. So it seems to be a design choice from either Java, or C/C++ (where Java inherited much of its basic semantics).

Comment: C++ seems to allow it. So it's probably just a design choice of Java.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you declare a variable (`main` in this case):

```
Main main = new Main();
```

it doesn't count as a statement, even if it has side-effects. For it to be a proper statement, you should just do

```
new Main();
```

---

So why is

```
... {
    Main main = new Main();
}
```

allowed? `{ ... }` is a block of code, and *does* count as a statement. In this case the `main` variable *could* be used after the declaration, but before the closing brace. Some compilers ignore the fact that it's indeed not used, other compilers emit warnings regarding this.

Comment: as 'Main main = new Main();' doesn't count as a statement, what is the official name for it in java? a expression?

Comment: It's called a variable declaration (with initialization).

Comment: so a variable declaration is not a statement in java?

Comment: Digging into this doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html, and find some explanation in parts 14.4 and 14.5, 'Main main = new Main();' is called LocalVariableDeclarationStatement, this indeed not count as 'statement' in 14.5 part.

Comment: In the javac codebase we have `class JCVariableDecl extends JCStatement` so I'd say it's safe to say that this is a type of statement.

Answer (score 3):

It can make sense to create a one-line block with a new statement. What doesn't make sense is to save a reference to a just created object inside a one-line block, because you can't access  variable main from outside the for scope.

Perhaps (just my guess) the compiler forces you to type the brackets explicitly because holding a reference doesn't make sense in that case, with the hope you become aware of the useless reference.

Answer (score 3):

[`for`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14) is defined as follows.

> ```
> BasicForStatement:
>     for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement
>
> ForStatementNoShortIf:
>     for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) StatementNoShortIf
>
> ForInit:
>     StatementExpressionList
>     LocalVariableDeclaration
>
> ForUpdate:
>     StatementExpressionList
>
> StatementExpressionList:
>     StatementExpression
>     StatementExpressionList , StatementExpression
> ```

[Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2) are defined as follows.

> A block is a sequence of statements, local class declarations, and
>   local variable declaration statements within braces.
>
> ```
> Block:
> { BlockStatementsopt }
>
> BlockStatements:
>     BlockStatement
>     BlockStatements BlockStatement
>
> BlockStatement:
>     LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
>     ClassDeclaration
>     Statement
> ```

[Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) are defined as follows.

> ```
> Statement:
>     StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
>     LabeledStatement
>     IfThenStatement
>     IfThenElseStatement
>     WhileStatement
>     ForStatement
>
> StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement:
>     Block
>     EmptyStatement
>     ExpressionStatement
>     AssertStatement
>     SwitchStatement
>     DoStatement
>     BreakStatement
>     ContinueStatement
>     ReturnStatement
>     SynchronizedStatement
>     ThrowStatement
>     TryStatement
>
> StatementNoShortIf:
>     StatementWithoutTrailingSubstatement
>     LabeledStatementNoShortIf
>     IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf
>     WhileStatementNoShortIf
>     ForStatementNoShortIf
> ```

According to the specification, `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement` (look at the block section) is invalid, if it's not declared within a block. Therefore, the following `for` loop reports a compile-time error "*not a statement*" as you mentioned in your question unless you use a pair of braces.

```
for (int a=0;a<10;a++)
        Main main=new Main();
```